# Toolwiz Time Freeze setting registers remotely Win 10

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to turning off and on the protection of Toolwiz remotely by setting the appropriate values to the registers:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Toolwiz\TimefreezeNew
CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE    REG_DWORD    0x0
NEXT_BOOT_PROTECT    REG_DWORD    0x1
I succeed to set and read the register remotely but unexpectedly the values of the register at the remote machine were different.
I set other register remotely but in this case all was OK.
I used python and psexec to run the commands.
Following are the commands:

```
A = 'psexec -s \\\\' 
A1 =  'psexec  \\\\' 
B = '  -u admin -p football'
REG_QUERY= ' reg query '
REG_ADD = ' reg add '
REG_CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE_SET =' /v CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE /t REG_DWORD /d 0'
REG_NEXT_BOOT_PROTECT_SET = ' /v NEXT_BOOT_PROTECT /t REG_DWORD /d 1'
TOOLWIZ_REGISTER = ' HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Toolwiz\\TimefreezeNew '
os.system( A + laptop + B + REG_ADD + TOOLWIZ_REGISTER + REG_CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE_SET)
```

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

Value CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE exists, overwrite(Yes/No)? y
The operation completed successfully.
reg exited on HAGALA-10-2 with error code 0.
0
`os.system( A + laptop + B + REG_QUERY + TOOLWIZ_REGISTER)` 
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Toolwiz\TimefreezeNew
CURRENT_PROTECT_MODE    REG_DWORD    0x0
NEXT_BOOT_PROTECT    REG_DWORD    0x1

reg exited on HAGALA-10-2 with error code 0.
0
The registers at the remote machine were 1,1 and didn't change.

I used another register to check the process.

os.system( A + laptop + B + REG_QUERY + CHECK_REGISTER)

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NativeWifiP\Parameters
DefaultFilterSettings    REG_DWORD    0x1
EnableWoWLAN    REG_DWORD    0x1
`REG_EnableWoWLAN_SET = ' /v EnableWoWLAN /t REG_DWORD /d 55 /f'`
`os.system( A + laptop + B + REG_ADD + CHECK_REGISTER + REG_EnableWoWLAN_SET)`

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

The operation completed successfully.
reg exited on HAGALA-10-2 with error code 0.
0
`os.system( A + laptop + B + REG_QUERY + CHECK_REGISTER)`

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NativeWifiP\Parameters
    DefaultFilterSettings    REG_DWORD    0x1
    EnableWoWLAN    REG_DWORD    0x37
```

I checked the value of the register at the remote machine and was 0x37.

I would appreciate if someone can help me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert and since it's been some time since you asked this question you may have already solved this.

BUT some time ago I was having troubles remotely freezing and unfreezing a machine and I discovered by chance that I could only make that work if I'd kill the timeFreeze process before calling the commands to freeze or unfreeze it. I don't know if this applies to your problem, since you're dealing directly with the registers, but I think it's worth trying.